# How do you set a view to a customized view family name in Revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I have not been able to see how to change a view family type to a different view family name...
For example, I have `"Detail Views (Detail)"`, which is the default location in the browser it places a new `ViewSection.CreateDetail` section.  But I want to place the view in another browser location I've created, called `"Detail Views (Beam Top Detail Views)"`.

What I've tried is `section.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VIEW_TYPE)`, which gives me the name it has used, but it will not let me follow that up with `.Set(NewViewName)` (same transaction).  Is there a way to set it directly during the `CreateDetail` entry, or do I have to run a separate transaction looking for all views of a given pattern, and change the setting there?

Answer (score 1):

When creating the detail you use the ElementId for the correct viewFamilyTypeId for "Detail Views (Beam Top Detail Views)".

Here's a link that might help you from Jeremy Tammik's blog on [thebuildingcoder.typepad.com](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/05/change-section-view-type-and-hide-cut-line.html)

The Revit 2014 SDK has sample code for ViewSection.CreateDetail method, which you can download on [Autodesk's website](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=2484975), if you don't want to install it from the install disk.

```
ViewFamilyType vt = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
    .Where(q => q.Name == "Detail Views (Beam Top Detail Views)")
    .First() as ViewFamilyType;
ElementId DetailViewId = vt.Id;
ViewSection newDetail = ViewSection.CreateDetail(document, DetailViewId, box);
```

If you'd like to change the ViewFamilyType **after** the view is created, this can be done using: `newDetail.ChangeTypeId(DetailViewId);`

Comment: Thanks......your suggestion was very helpful, although the string "Beam Top Detail Views" is the value I had to look for (put in parentheses automatically, with prefix of default "Detail View").  The next thing I have to code is creating new "Detail Views" -- which I assume I have to copy, probably from the default type.

Comment: Note also that if the ViewFamilyType q.name result is unpopulated, the addition of the .First() code causes a failure.....there have to be members of that ViewFamilyType, even if it has been created.  I'll have to seek a solution that works for the first view created after the ViewFamilyType has been created.